# Mac app encode mp3 with LAME

Tags: objective-c, c, mp3

How would you be able to convert a .mp4 or AAC that is stored on disk into an mp3 using lame? It seems like it should be easy but I can't se to get a working demo. Any help is appreciated.

To be clear, I want to call LAME from within an OS X app; it is open-source as well, so no worries about licensing.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like using the Terminal stop reading :) There are other possibilities to use lame but I'll describe the one using the Terminal:

You can get it here:
http://lame.sourceforge.net/

Download the latest version

Open the Terminal and `cd` to the directory you unpacked it to and
type the following:

```
sudo su
./configure
make
make install
```

After that you can navigate to any directory and use the `lame` command.
A standard call would be

```
lame infile.aac outfile.mp3
```

But you can specify numerous options like samplerate, tag information, ...
Read this for more info:

```
man lame
```

Cheers

Comment: That is helpful, but I think I wasn't clear enough. I have an open-source mac project that I want to call lame from within. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Do you want to call the lame comand from the app, or do you want to compile the lame codec into your app? Either of them I don't know how to do it without researching, but probably someone else can help?

Comment: I ended up using NSTask to call it.